# How can I wait for form to completely load before printing document

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using "print document" to capture a screenshot of a form and print it immediately after it loads. I have used the "form shown" event but the image still comes out as partially loaded!!! What can I do that will help it print properly.

```
    Bitmap bmp;

    public void initiatePrint()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        bmp = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height, g);
        Graphics mg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        mg.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, this.Size);
        printPreviewDialogPrint.ShowDialog();

        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage_1(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, (e.PageBounds.Width - bmp.Width) / 2, (e.PageBounds.Height - bmp.Height) / 2, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    }

    private void FPrint_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initiatePrint();
    }
```

Here is my printing code.

Comment: The Shown event is a bit misleading, it only tells you that the form finished painting itself but not the controls, they'll get their Paint event next.  Easy to fix, add `this.Update();`

Comment: you could use the page-life-cycle to call  initiatePrint() in the method onLoad here some info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx